# After migration to Android X app crashes android.view.InflateException

Tags: android, androidx

After migration app to Android X app crashed in runtime. It happens when Activity of Fragment inflates layout. My StackTrace is:

> Process: com.sizestream.android, PID: 17380
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {package/...Activity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #50: Error inflating class 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
>           at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
>           at com.common.mvvm.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:43)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2530)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:887)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1233)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1299)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:688)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2069)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1859)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1814)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1721)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:447)
>           at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResume(FragmentActivity.java:444)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7117)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>   2019-03-18 13:05:21.536 17380-17380/com.sizestream.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

Answer (score 5):

After some debugging I have found issue occurs when project has used [material-components-android](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) before migration and some things must be done manually:

1. **TextInputLayout** child view should be **com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText** instead of EditText or AppCompatEditText:

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
               android:id="@+id/input_layout"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content">

               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                   android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
   ```
2. **TextInputLayout** should use **android:theme** and **app:errorTextAppearance** inherited from **Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox**

styles.xml:

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    ...
</style>
<style name="TextInputLayoutErrorAppearance" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox">
    ...
</style>
```

layout.xml

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/input_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:errorTextAppearance="@style/TextInputLayoutErrorAppearance">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

3. If you have toggle for password input type **app:passwordToggleEnabled** and **app:passwordToggleTint** must be replaced to **app:endIconMode="password_toggle"**

   ```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                   android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   app:errorEnabled="true"
                   app:endIconMode="password_toggle">


               <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                       android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:inputType="textPassword"/>
   ```

Comment: You have got the solution while posting the question. That's the great achievement mate!

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to share my solution because there is no much info related to that issue ;)